# Proof (uv is odd if and only if u and v are odd)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given two integers u and v, prove the following.

uv is odd if and only if u and v are odd

[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmrbx.jpg)
[image: My solution here]

Am I prove it completely?
If not, what's wrong with it and how can i prove that?

Comment: Your solution looks good but you probably want to put it in LaTeX notation for clarity.

Comment: Please delete the graphic from your question, and instead format the math via [mathjax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @merelymyself I disagree that the solution looks good, I find it incomplete, and posted an answer accordingly.

Comment: The image is hardly legible.  Please attempt to learn use mathjax, even just the basics.  Don't make it difficult for the best of answerers to help out.

Comment: Indeed, this is difficult to read. Since the presentation was not improved on request, I voted to close as “needs details or clarity.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is fine but, as noticed, not complete, in a more simple and concise way it suffices to check directly

- $u \lor v$ even $\implies uv$ even, indeed let wlog $u=2w$ then $uv=2wv$
- $u \land v$ odd $\implies uv$ odd, indeed $uv=(2k+1)(2h+1)=4kh+2(h+k)+1=2j+1$

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is incomplete.

You proved (subject to some minor remarks, to be addressed below) that if $uv$ is odd, then each of $u$ and $v$ is odd.

You did not provide (any attempt at) a proof that if each of $u$ and $v$ is odd then $uv$ must also be odd. The question asks for "if and only if", this has two parts and you addressed only one of them (namely that if $uv$ is odd then so are each of $u$ and $v$) but not the other part.

Regarding the way you wrote it, and the parts circled red, here is my best guess as to what is wrong with them. They are not really wrong, just the way it is written may not express precisely what you mean.

"Let there exists an odd $k=uv$": usually when you say "Let" you already know for sure that what you wanted to exist does indeed exist. So, if you don't know whether it does exist, then a better way to phrase that would be:
"Suppose (towards a contradiction that) there existed an odd $k=uv$", or
"Suppose (towards a contradiction that) there was(were) an odd $k=uv$", or
"Assume (to the contrary, that) there existed an odd $k=uv$".
It would also be appropriate (in particular for an exam or homework) to first announce which direction of the proof you would be attempting. Something like:
"We will first prove that if $uv$ is odd, then so is each of $u$ and $v$.
Assume to the contrary, that there existed an odd $k=uv$ such that at least
one of $u$ or $v$ is even. Consider the following cases:
Case 1. Exactly one of $u$ and $v$ is even. By switching (interchanging) $u$ and $v$ if necessary we may assume without loss of generality that $u$ is even and $v$ is odd.
Then (...the rest of your case 1, as you wrote it).
Case 2. Both $u$ and $v$ are even, (then rest of your case 2)."

What you wrote after case 2 is correct, though "does not exist" is circled red, perhaps because you wrote "Let there exists" at the beginning, instead of the more appropriate "Assume towards a contradiction that there existed...". Just a matter of language, perhaps.

Again, your proof that if $uv$ is odd (for integer $u,v$) then each of $u$ and $v$ is odd, is correct (subject to minor improvements how to write it). But, you did not provide a proof (at least in your picture) that if $u$ and $v$ each is odd, then $uv$ is odd. Thus, you only proved one direction of the "if and only if" part,
roughly half of what you were asked to do. To make it complete, the proof may continue as follows.
"Next we will prove (the other direction, namely) that if each of $u$ and $v$ is odd then so is their product $uv$. (Provide your own proof here.)"